# Stacked Notification in Android Handheld

Tags: android, notifications

I've been trying to create stacked notifications for the android handheld. Something like this:

[image]

My GCM Broadcast receiver receives different notifications at different point of time. I want to combine all those into a single notification.

Currently, this is possible for wear devices using this: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html

How do I do it for a handheld? I have a group notification id that can be used to combine notifications.

Please note that this is not same as [Inbox Style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.InboxStyle.html) Notification. There you have to have all notifications to create the stack using `.addLine()` method. My notifications come in time, successively.

Answer (score 0):

Stacked notifications (or Bundled) are only available in the Android N preview

http://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-updates.html#bundle

Comment: Okay. I want to do it for 5.x or lower. I'm pretty it is possible (all apps do it)

Comment: show an example of "all apps doing it" because it does not exist

Comment: Above screenshot is one. Whatsapp, slack, any messenger. Another example [link](http://wear.techbrood.com/preview/images/notifications/stack_combo.png)

Comment: above screen shot is not one, that is the InboxStyle you referenced and so is the other link

Comment: Yes, I know that. Now the questions= is how to do it in my case. There should be a way.

Comment: You have to keep track of your notifications somehow in your app, most these apps have a database with an `is_read` flag on it or something and thats how they get populated